# Meteor.js.Demo applications for package "ostrio:files".How upload file in localhost in linux system

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Hi ran the demo applications for package "ostrio:files" located at the address:
https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files

I installed in Linux and Meteor.js version 1.4.1.1. For running applications made the upload pdf file. Clicking on the link to the stated file is not generated preview(Preview is not available, please download file) and I have no way to save the file on your computer(The failure of a network error).

Command "mongo meteor" I checked the contents of data collection:

`{ "_id" : "EytqjTjQN99zDt9Ld", "name" : "uokik_zakupy_przez_internet_ulotka.pdf", "extension" : "pdf", "path" : "assets/app/uploads/uploadedFiles/EytqjTjQN99zDt9Ld.pdf", "meta" : { "blamed" : 0, "secured" : false, "expireAt" : ISODate("2016-09-01T06:04:44.082Z"), "unlisted" : false, "downloads" : 0, "created_at" : 1472623484081 }, "type" : "application/pdf", "size" : 219032, "versions" : { "original" : { "path" : "assets/app/uploads/uploadedFiles/EytqjTjQN99zDt9Ld.pdf", "size" : 219032, "type" : "application/pdf", "extension" : "pdf" } }, "isVideo" : false, "isAudio" : false, "isImage" : false, "isText" : false, "isJSON" : false, "isPDF" : true, "_storagePath" : "assets/app/uploads/uploadedFiles", "_downloadRoute" : "/cdn/storage", "_collectionName" : "uploadedFiles", "public" : false }`

I noticed that the file should be saved in the path "assets/app/uploads/uploadedFiles". Is to save on server localhost Linux I have to create the system path. If so, in which directory.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create dir.
Read doc, it creates dir.
https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/files

Where are files stored by default?: by default if config.storagePath isn't passed into Constructor it's equals to assets/app/uploads and relative to running script:

On development stage: yourDevAppDir/.meteor/local/build/programs/server. Note: All files will be removed as soon as your application rebuilds or you run meteor reset. To keep your storage persistent during development use an absolute path outside of your project folder, e.g. /data directory.

On production: yourProdAppDir/programs/server. Note: If using MeteorUp (MUP), Docker volumes must to be added to mup.json, see MUP usage